# Packaging Android Wear Apps

Tags: android, wear-os

Anyone know if there's available documentation for packaging wearable apps? The "Packaging Wearable Apps" link is typoed in http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

to

http://developer.android.com/traiing/wearables/packaging.html

and even http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/packaging.html is a 404.

The app is written and I can install it directly to a Samsung Gear Live, so looking to get the app onto the Play Store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Packaging Wearable Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) link in the left-hand navigation area.

Comment: Ah cool, didn't notice that. Thanks. Also, since you're right there and all, thanks for the MergeAdapter library :p I love that thing.

Comment: @PaulRuiz: I'm glad that you find `MergeAdapter` useful! BTW, I have not tried those packaging instructions. This week's Android code/tools release has been rocky (to say the least), so YMMV.

Comment: Got it up and working. Just needed the one line in the mobile section build.gradle file, then it's the standard signing and zipalign setup. Got the app up and source/tutorial posted: http://ptrprograms.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Also when developing (debug) and testing your release on the same wear device it might be required to hit the "sync apps" option from the wear app on your phone/tablet.

In my case the wear app didn't appear on the wearable until I did so. The packaging itself was done with android studio and I only had to add the wearApp in dependencies and build with release config for the wear app to be included.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+''
   wearApp project(':wearable')
}
```

More at: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html